# $H\trianglelefteq A$ and $K\trianglelefteq B\Rightarrow HK\trianglelefteq AB$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $A, B\leq G$. Suppose $H\trianglelefteq A$ and $K\trianglelefteq B$. Is it true that $HK\trianglelefteq AB$?

**Notation:** $\leq$ means subgroup and $\trianglelefteq$ means normal subgroup.

Thanks

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of some larger group $G$?

Comment: Yes, I'll add that up..

Answer (score 4):

It is false. Take $H=\{1\}, A=G,$ and $K=B$. If the assumption was true we would have $K\lhd G$ but $K$ can be any subgroup.

Comment: where is your $g$? Don't forget the normality of $H$ and $K$ is with respect to $A$ and $B$, respectively..

Comment: In other words, if this was true all subgroups would be norma

Comment: Very nice indeed. +1

Comment: Yes, I agree...

Answer (score 1):

No.

First of all, the set $AB$ is not in general a subgroup, consider eg $H = A$ and $K = B$ for easy examples.

Even if it is, the claim is false. Consider $G = B$, $H = A$. The claim fails since it is possible to find examples where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, $K$ is normal in $G$, but $HK$ is not a normal subgroup.

Comment: You're right $HK$ is a subgroup of $g$ if and only if $HK=KH$..